# Test Method returning error "Assertion after the final `assert.async` was resolved"

Tags: unit-testing, qunit, sinon

I am trying to test javascript method as below,

```
var spyPostRender = sinon.spy(proxy, "postRender");
var done = assert.async();
proxy.init();
done();
assert.ok(spyPostRender.calledOnce, "postRender() function was called.");
```

where init() internally calls an ajax service, however when I do this, I am getting below error. Can anybody help me in resolving this issue?

> Assertion after the final assert.async was resolved@ 85 ms Source:at
>   Object.QUnit.assert.Assert.ok
>   (http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.17.1.js:1296:8)

FYI - I am using QUnit-1.17.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are immediately calling the `done()` function after you call `init()`, that is incorrect. You should only call the `done()` method was asynchronous activity has completed (hence the word "done"). The easy way to accomplish this is to add a callback function to your `init()` method:

```
proxy.init = function(callback) {
  // just using jQuery as an example, could be any framework...
  $.ajax({
    url: "/some/api/service",
    // ...
    complete: function() {
      callback(/* maybe pass some data back? */);
    }
  });
};
```

And then you can pass an anonymous function in when you test it:

```
QUnit.test("Test the init method", function(assert) {
  var spyPostRender = sinon.spy(proxy, "postRender");
  var done = assert.async();
  proxy.init(function() {
    assert.ok(spyPostRender.calledOnce, "postRender() function was called.");
    // Notice that we only call done() once everything async is complete!
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah I think the documentation on assert.async() and the corresponding done() function is a little too vague on  QUnits website.   I mean, the general idea is that after all asynchronous activity is *done* then call the done() function to tell QUnit to resume its activity.  However, its not explicit where the activity is stopped or what is considered asyncronous activity,  I got tripped up on this one too,  I thought I could call assert.equal(A,B) after the done() function also, since I saved the result within a callback function anyway, however this was not the case.  Thanks Jakerella!

Answer (score 0):

First solution is posted by @jakarella, alternative solution without modifying the existing code is using sinon.stub

Or else perhaps use a sinon.stub to override proxy.postRender to perform your async assertions:

```
var done = assert.async();

var _postRender = proxy.postRender;
var stubPostRender = sinon.stub(proxy, "postRender", function() {
  var result = _postRender.apply(this, arguments);

    // Do your real assertions BEFORE invoking the final (i.e. you may have multiple) `done` callback
  assert.ok(stubPostRender.calledOnce, "postRender() function was called.");

  // The final `done` callback MUST be called AFTER all real assertions have been made
  done();

  return result;
});

proxy.init();
```

Above code is copied from github solution 
https://github.com/jquery/qunit/issues/777